# Show Zero if there is no record count - ORACLE SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

The below Oracle query gives if there are any different errors with `error_message` and `Serial_num`.

If there is ZERO or No `Different error` count instead of showing Blank/Null result.  How can i see the output like this?  I tried with `NVL(error_message,0)` and `COALESCE (Sum(total),0)` but not getting the desired output.

**Expected output**:

```
1   Different Errors:       0
```

Oracle SQL Query:

```sql
SELECT 
  1 as Index_Num, 
  CONCAT('Different Errors:  ', error_message || '# ' || serial_num), 
  SUM(total) 
FROM ( 
  SELECT error_message, serial_num, COUNT(*) total 
  FROM Table1 
  WHERE error_message NOT LIKE '%INVALID%' 
  GROUP BY error_message, serial_num
) 
GROUP BY error_message, serial_num
```

Comment: Are you checking for `NULL` values or does `error_message` actually contain the text `NULL`?  To check for `NULL` values you use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: updated WHERE clause

Comment: What output are you seeing?

Comment: Your inner query will give you the counts of the different error messages, by serial number.  Since your outer query is doing a `GROUP BY` with the same columns, it isn't really doing anything beyond that aside from creating the new column using `CONCAT`.

Comment: Yes. Generally if there are proper Errors then the count shows `1.    Different Errors: 
Some error occurred for mismatch serials # 343543532       1`

Comment: And if there are no errors, do you just an empty query set (i.e. 0 rows returned)?

Comment: Yes......Correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `CTE` for the subquery and use `UNION ALL` with `NOT EXISTS` to cover the case that the `CTE` does not return any rows:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT error_message, serial_num, COUNT(*) total 
  FROM Table1 
  WHERE error_message NOT LIKE '%INVALID%' 
  GROUP BY error_message, serial_num
)
SELECT 
  1 as Index_Num, 
  CONCAT(
    'Different Errors:  ', 
    list_agg(error_message || '# ' || serial_num) within group (order by error_message)
  ), 
  SUM(total) 
FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Different Errors:  ', 0
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte)
```

Comment: Error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Comment: I assumed that your code works for the case that there are rows returned by the subquery and you only need help for the case it does not return any rows. Or not?

Comment: Correct. Generally if there are proper Errors then the outcome is `1.    Different Errors: 
Some error occurred for mismatch serials # 343543532       1`. Here the error_message is `Some error occurred for mismatch serials` and Serial_num is `343543532` and the last value `1` is the total sum/count

Comment: So if your code works, adding UNION ALL to it should also work. I changed to list_agg() just in case the subquery returns more than 1 rows.

Comment: Seems SUM(total) has to be changed to NVL(SUM(total),0) or COALESCE (SUM(total),0). Otherwise the SUM shows BLANK value without 0.

Comment: SUM(total) sums the counts of the subquery and cannot be NULL unless there are no rows returned by the subquery and then UNION ALL will return 0 from the 2nd query.

Comment: See the screenshot.  https://imgur.com/a/cfr8ZsI. only one row is enough when there are '0' error_message count and rows with error_message required when there're are multiple errors with different serial_num.

Comment: Make a fiddle:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2 with sample data to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

D'oh!  Looks like I took too long.  Here's another option for posterity:

```sql
SELECT 
  1, 
  CONCAT(
    'Different Errors:  ', 
    CASE 
      WHEN src.error_message IS NULL THEN '' 
      ELSE src.error_message || ' # ' || src.serial_num 
    END
  ) Summary,
  COALESCE(src.total, 0) AS total
FROM dual -- Get a seed row (in case there are no rows in error table)
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT error_message, serial_num, COUNT(*) total 
  FROM Table1 
  WHERE error_message NOT LIKE '%INVALID%' 
  GROUP BY error_message, serial_num
) src ON 0=0
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7efd5c/2)

Comment: Thank you very much @ravioli I found your code useful for my work. Upvoted :)

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly what you are asking for, but might prove useful.  You can easily add a row with the total number of errors, using `grouping sets`:

```
SELECT 1 as Index_Num, 
       ('Different Errors:  ' || error_message || '# ' || serial_num), 
       COUNT(*) as total 
FROM Table1 
WHERE error_message NOT LIKE '%INVALID%' 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (error_message, serial_num), () );
```

Alas, this produces the summary row even when there are errors.  It occurs to me that you might find this useful.